# Session data lost in custom magento module

Tags: session, core-session

I have a custom module with two controllers.

In the first controller (`SetupController`), if I were to set some session data like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
    ->setData('BuyerCookie', 'A1B2C3');

var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData()); // I see the session value
```

Then, in another controller (`TestController`), if I try to retrieve the value from session like this:

```
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData()); // My session value is not there
```

Any ideas what might be happening? How do you set global session data and retrieve it?

I tried using cookie by utilising `Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')` and it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Do you set the session value within a controller action or earlier, like constructor or `preDispatch`?

Comment: I set it within a controller action and try to retrieve it within a controller action also.

Comment: After doing this `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBuyerCookie('A1B2C3');` in my `SetupController` index action, in the other `TestController` index action I did the following: `echo '<pre>'; print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData()); exit;` and this is what I am getting back (notice my data is not present): http://pastebin.com/raw/qANj0v1i

Comment: I have also tried the same thing using cookie (i.e. `Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie')`) and still getting the same issue. I don't know why the data is getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting of session cookie management on admin panel.

I think that the cookie is not being set because of some wrong settings.

Comment: Cookie storage is set to `db` (not `file`). That's the only setting in terms of session setting I changed. What should I look for specifically in admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend this method to set session

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBuyerCookie('A1B2C3');
```

and get it

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getBuyerCookie();
```

Comment: I will give this a go, but I thought the two methods were same (the one I am using and the one you recommended).

Comment: once i got the same problem someone recommend this method..

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. After doing this `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBuyerCookie('A1B2C3');` in my `SetupController` index action, in the other `TestController` index action I did the following: `echo '<pre>'; print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData()); exit;` and this is what I am getting back (notice my data is not present): http://pastebin.com/raw/qANj0v1i